# Fullpage.js - How do I trigger the onLeave function only once?

Tags: javascript, css, fullpage.js

I have a page where I'm creating several animations with the Fullpage.js onLeave function and CSS.

My problem is when I leave the second section, the animations on section 3 are running great. But when I scroll back to section 2 and go down to section 3 again, the animations are bugged - I'm trying to make the onleave function only run once and then keep the classes as they are.

Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    //options here

    scrollOverflow:true,
    scrollingSpeed: 900,
    navigation: true,
    slidesNavigation: true,
  
      onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){
      var loadedSection = this;
      
      //Section 2 Eigenschaften
      if(origin.index == 1 && direction == 'down'){
        
        //Gradient Hintergrund
        $(".gradientcircle").toggleClass("animate");
        
        //Eigenschaften Titel Opacity 1S Delay
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(".eigenschaften").toggleClass("animate1");
            }, 1000);
        
        //Eigenschaften Titel TranslateY 2S Delay
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(".eigenschaften").toggleClass("animate2");
            }, 2000);
      }
      
      //SECTION 3 KENNTNISSE
      if(origin.index == 2 && direction == 'down'){
        
        //White Circle Background
        $(".whitecircle").toggleClass("animate");
        
        //Grey Circle Background
        $(".greycircle").toggleClass("animate");
        
        //Gradient Hintergrund
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(".gradientcircle2").toggleClass("animate");
            }, 500);
        
        //KENNTNISSE TITEL
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(".kenntnisse-titel").toggleClass("animate");
            }, 1500);
        
        //KENNTNISSE SUBTITLE
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(".kenntnisse-subtitle").toggleClass("animate");
            }, 1750);
        
        //KENNTNISSE SHORTCODE
        setTimeout(function(){
          $(".kenntnisse-shortcode").toggleClass("animate");
            }, 2000);
       
      }
    }
 });
});
```

Does someone know how to trigger the onLeave function only once?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to keep track of the current state and to know if the animation was already fired or not.

Something like:

```js
var numSections = 10;
var isAnimationFired = new Array(numSections).fill(false);

...

new fullpage('#fullpage', {
  onLeave: function(origin, destination, direction){

    // checking the flag to see if animation was fired for 
    // this destination section
    if(!isAnimationFired[destination.index]){
      if(destination.index === 1){
          // fire animation
          fireAnimationHere();
    
          isAnimationFired[destination.index] = true;
      }
    }
  }
});
```